# sharding on Mysql server

Tags: mysql, nosql

I have just created a cluster on Mongodb(I used sharding technique), and my question is how can I do this technique(sharding) on MYsql.and what is it called in mysql.tks

Answer (score 2):

Some others before you have asked this question before, and here are the answers they got:

[MySQL sharding approaches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541421/mysql-sharding-approaches)
[Scaling solutions for MySQL (Replication, Clustering)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189903/scaling-solutions-for-mysql-replication-clustering/195131)
[MySQL Partitioning / Sharding / Splitting - which way to go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879/mysql-partitioning-sharding-splitting-which-way-to-go)